# Please how can i fix this "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int" in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i keep getting the error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int and i don't know whats wrong.
The error is in this line "if( $result > 0 ){"

```
public function index()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwd', 'passwd', 'required|min_length[5]');
        
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else{
        $where = array(
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'passwd' =>$_POST['passwd'] ,
            );

        $result = $this->LoginModel->login_user($where);
        if( $result > 0 ){
            $sessiondata = array(
                'email'    => $where['email'],
                'id'     => $result->id,
                'name'     => $result->name,
                
              );
        $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
        return redirect('Location: home');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'wrong details');
            return redirect('Welcome');
            $this->db->close();
        }
    }
}
```

And my model

```
 public function login_user($where){
    $query = $this->db->where($where)
                    ->get('admin');
    if ($query-> num_rows() > 0) 
        return $query->row();
    else
        return false;               
    
}
```

Comment: It means `$result` is an object. So asking whether an object is greater than zero makes (ironically) zero sense. A number and an object are not comparable things - how can a non-numeric thing be "greater"?. Are you actually trying to test whether the query returned some rows? Or if the query failed? Because your login_user function returns the result of `$query->row()` (when successful), which itself will return an object containing all the fields in the first row the query returned. Whereas if it fails it'll return false, so maybe `if ($result != false)` would make more sense as a test.

Comment: you are returning truthy/falsey from your function so you can just do this: `if($result){...`

Comment: **Warning!** Looking at your code, you seem to be storing passwords in plain text. **Don't do that!** You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).